# google map url - how do I show address when passing lat and long in url to google maps in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, url-scheme

My problem is that when I am opening **google map** using the following code.

It's showing lat long in place of address. But i want to show address in google map, or is there any way to pass custom address along with lat long so that google map will show custom address on search bar (coming on top of the image) and show exact location on map with marker.

I had follow the documentation of URLSchemes given by Google.[ios-urlscheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme)

But didn't get any proper solution which fills my conditions.

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?q=40.00026321411133,-83.03424072265625&center=40.00026321411133,-83.03424072265625"))
```

[image]

Comment: hi, find the address from lat and long the pass it to google map url instead of lat and long. like said in the link in question.

Comment: Hello Ben, no its not working. If i am passing address in query of above googlemap scheme url then it will show all related results matching the string with multiple markers. But i want to show only single marker and single result for which i am passing lat long.

Comment: have you tried this. comgooglemaps://?q=Pizza&center=37.759748,-122.427135

Comment: instead of title Pizza pass the address that's separately find.

Comment: yes i tried this. In the url it's giving multiple results with marker not showing to particular coordinate which i am passing in center query param.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass address venue name also with the lat-long:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

func openMapForPlace() {

    let lat1 : NSString = self.venueLat
    let lng1 : NSString = self.venueLng

    let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
    let longitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue

    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let address = [CNPostalAddressStreetKey: address ?? "",
                   CNPostalAddressCityKey: city ?? "",
                   CNPostalAddressStateKey: state ?? "",
                   CNPostalAddressPostalCodeKey: zipCode,
                   CNPostalAddressISOCountryCodeKey: isoCountryCodeKey ?? ""]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: address)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "\(self.venueName)"
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

In `swift` code will be below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        openMapForPlace()
    }

    func openMapForPlace() {

        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 39.9517958
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -75.1611398

        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let address = [CNPostalAddressStreetKey: "1234 Market St",
                   CNPostalAddressCityKey: "Philadelphia",
                   CNPostalAddressStateKey: "Pennsylvania",
                   CNPostalAddressPostalCodeKey: "19107",
                   CNPostalAddressISOCountryCodeKey: "USA"]
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: address)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "1234 Market St, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania, 19107"
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: Above code is for Apple map, but i need for Google map.

Comment: @ManishaSharma, is it fixed for you? I am also facing same issue with GoogleMap Url  Scheme in iOS.